# How is Nettys FileDescriptor usage on OS X

Tags: java, macos, tcp, netty

in the PLC4X project we are using Netty for the clients to connect to PLCs which act as server. Sometimes, either by user error or by PLC error the connections are not accepted but rejected. If we retry to build up the connection ASAP multiple times, we run into the error message `Too many open files`.
I try to clean up everything in my code, so I would assume that there are no filedescriptors that could leak:

```
try {
  final NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

  Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
  bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
  bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
  bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
  bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
  // TODO we should use an explicit (configurable?) timeout here
  // bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000);
  bootstrap.handler(channelHandler);
  // Start the client.
  final ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect(address, port);
  f.addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {
      @Override public void operationComplete(Future<? super Void> future) throws Exception {
          if (!future.isSuccess()) {
              logger.info("Unable to connect, shutting down worker thread.");
              workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
          }
      }
  });
  // Wait for sync
  f.sync();
  f.awaitUninterruptibly(); // jf: unsure if we need that
  // Wait till the session is finished initializing.
  return f.channel();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  throw new PlcConnectionException("Error creating channel.", e);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new PlcConnectionException("Error creating channel.", e);
}
```

From my understanding, the Listener should always shutdown the group and free up all descriptors used.
But in reality, when running it on macOS Catalina I see that about 1% of the fails that its not due to "rejection" but due to "Too many open files".
Is this a `ulimit` thing, as Netty (on macOS) simply needs a number of fd's to use? Or am I leaking something?

Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution, kind of myself.
There are 2 issues (probably even 3) in an original implementation, which are not really related to Mac OS X:

- connect and addListener should be chained
- `workerGroup.shutdownGracefully()` is triggered in another thread, so the main (called) thread already finishes
- its not awaited that the workerGroup really finishes.

This together can lead to situations as it seems, where new groups are spawned faster than old groups are closed.
Thus, I changed the implementation to

```
try {
    final NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
    bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
    // TODO we should use an explicit (configurable?) timeout here
    // bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000);
    bootstrap.handler(channelHandler);
    // Start the client.
    logger.trace("Starting connection attempt on tcp layer to {}:{}", address.getHostAddress(), port);
    final ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect(address, port);
    // Wait for sync
    try {
        f.sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Shutdown worker group here and wait for it
        logger.info("Unable to connect, shutting down worker thread.");
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully().awaitUninterruptibly();
        logger.debug("Worker Group is shutdown successfully.");
        throw new PlcConnectionException("Unable to Connect on TCP Layer to " + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port, e);
    }
    // Wait till the session is finished initializing.
    return f.channel();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new PlcConnectionException("Error creating channel.", e);
}
```

which adresses the issues above. Thus, the call only finishes when its properly cleaned up.

My tests now show a constant number of open file descriptors.